# How to install Windows 7 printer drivers on XP print server?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, shared-printers

We have a shared printer connected via USB to (and shared on the network from) an XP system being accessed by a combination of XP and Windows 7 workstations across the network.

What is the best method to install the Windows 7 (x86 and x64) drivers on the XP system so that network users can download them automatically as they add the printer?

I have dealt with this before, but now I can't remember how I worked around the fact that Windows 7 isn't listed as an Environment in the "Additional Drivers" window.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Document everything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the error I was getting that I misinterpreted:

[image]

The Windows 7 driver was on the "server" (XP system) the whole time. The installer had drivers for XP -> Windows 8, so I was surprised to get this error and just assumed the worst.

That error was appearing because I had replaced a printer with a different model but had given it the same share name (intentionally- to keep things simple for users).

The Windows 7 client realized it no longer had the correct driver for the printer so gave an error I had not seen before.

I *assumed* the driver was not on the print server, or it would have downloaded it automatically- but this was not the case.

All I had to do was right-click on the printer in "Devices and Printers" and choose "Update driver" on each client machine (only 20).

If anyone else sees that "Driver Update Needed" error- it might be easier to fix than you think. However, you are only likely to see this error if you replace a printer with a different model- but keep the exact same share name (*\\SameServerName\SamePrinterName*)

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Windows XP is almost 12 years old and has been superseded by 3 new versions already. Step away from the obsolete software!

Besides that, on a server you install a server operating system, such as windows server 2012.

Comment: I just got it working with Win7 x86 and x64 (two different model printers as well). I take your point about XP being old- we have nearly finished upgrading OS's. The reason the printer wasn't attached to the server is this spare workstation is more powerful than the server (it's a not-for-profit... server upgrade overdue). Anyway it's working great now. I just had to right-click on the printer and choose "Update driver" on the clients (new printer has same share name as previous printer- never saw the "Update driver message" before and thought it was worse than it really was.)

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to install additional drivers on window xp. here perform steps to printer work on both PC.

1.Install printer on window xp with universal 32 bit driver name as PCL5.(Search with name HP Universal Driver pcl5 32 bit on google to download)

2.Share your printer on network.

3.open windows 7 and install dummy printer with universal 64 bit driver name as PCL5.(Search with name HP Universal Driver pcl5 64 bit on google to download)

4.After installation remove dummy printer.

5.Now install shared printer (on window xp). this time window 7 64 bit auto pic driver because it has already cache the drivers in last steps.

I am using this technique athome with my old P4 PC with window XP having shared printer for all :-)